# debugPaintSizeEnabled is not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I just began learning flutter and built the sample app present in [Building Layout tutorial](https://flutter.io/tutorials/layout/).

> In the [source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/website/master/_includes/code/layout/lakes/main.dart) it's suggested to un-comment two lines, to see the visual debug lines, but so far no luck.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Uncomment lines 7 and 10 to view the visual layout at runtime.
//import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart' show debugPaintSizeEnabled;

void main() {
  //debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

> What I have tried?

1. Hot Reload
2. Full Restart
3. Setting other debug variables to true:

```
debugPaintPointersEnabled = 
    debugPaintBaselinesEnabled = 
    debugPaintLayerBordersEnabled = 
    debugRepaintRainbowEnabled = true;
```

, which I read from [Docs](https://flutter.io/debugging/#visual-debugging). They worked fine.

> My Setup?

1. Visual Studio Code
2. No Dart 2 Preview Mode
3. Flutter Beta
4. I use an Android Mobile Hardware, not Virtual (Moto G5)

> Question: How to make the visual debugger work?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and the only solution i found, is to toggle debug painting from VSCode command palette.

`Flutter: Toggle Debug Painting`

You can also make it works using the rendering library.

First you need to import it

`import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';`

Then, set debugPaintSizeEnabled to true in the main method of your application or in a widget's build method

```
void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled=true;
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

You need to fully restart your application to apply effects

Here's the [official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging#visual-debugging).

Comment: I don't get that command in my command palette, am I missing something?.

All I see after, ctrl + shift + p then typing Flutter, is two options: 

Flutter: Run Flutter Doctor & Flutter: New Project

Comment: Make sure your project is running and you should see more options.
Versions i am running with :
- flutter : 0.1.5
- dart code extension : 2.10.0

Comment: I don't see the the command in my command palette either. I see a bunch of flutter ones but not Toggle Debug Painting

Comment: This adds a very small grid, not very useful.

Comment: There is no such toggle.

Comment: @Champe it worked by putting it into the build method of either a widget I am using or one that I'm not.  Opened a github issue about this.

Answer (score 13):

Add import statements :

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
```

Then in the build add the debugPaintSizeEnabled=true; like :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPaintSizeEnabled=true;
```

Comment: Initializing that variable inside build worked, the example in official site is misleading. But the answer to this question, is a much better solution though, we don't even need to import any dependencies!

Comment: small tiny grids are useless.

Answer (score 7):

It's not necessary import anything in VSCode, just:

1. Open command palette by <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd></kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> for mac)
2. Type `Flutter: Toggle Debug Painting` and click on it: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMDIc.png).

Answer (score 3):

> **UPDATE**
>
> The following steps work on both **android device** and **android
>   virtual device** if you are working with ANDROID STUDIO. It works only
>   on **Android virtual device** if you are working wih VSCode

I was following the same tutorial recently to learn all about the layout elements in Flutter. 
To enable visual layout at runtime, what I did was quite straightforward -

- First

> I added **import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart' show debugPaintSizeEnabled;** at the top of my **main.dart** file

- Next

> I added **debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;** to my main() method

```
void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

- Finally

> I performed a **full restart** of my app to reflect all the changes. *It doesn't reflect changes if you perform a hot reload.*

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem as you have just now. my solution is: do not restart from VS Code debugger, it is tricky. just use `flutter run -d deviceID` to restart your app. it will be OK.

Answer (score 3):

In the terminal press 'p'

```
To toggle the display of construction lines (debugPaintSizeEnabled), press "p".
```

*(this is the easiest option!)*

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';`

Comment: He would get an error message if an import were missing

Answer (score 0):

1. import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
2. > void main() {
   >       debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
   >       runApp(new MyApp());    }
3. Open command palette by CTRL + SHIFT + P (for window),
4. type Flutter: Toggle Debug Painting and click on it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, wasn't able to see any debug information.

Fixed it by running in debug mode instead of profile or release.
Maybe this will help someone.